# strlen and free memory

Tags: c, malloc, free, strlen

I allocated memory to a pointer to the maximum size of characters it could have.
Then I had to write code that will change its values depending on the value that was read from the file and I needed to know what is the length of the value in the pointer, so I used `strlen()` function.

I got what I needed.
The problem occured when I tried to free the memory of that pointer. The program crashed, I'm assuming im doing something "ilegal" and would like to know why and how to fix it.

here is part of the code:

```
char *StudID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
char *StudIDcpy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
fread(stud[i].ID, sizeof(char), 4, in);
stud[i].ID[4] = '\0';
IDtemp = atoi(stud[i].ID);//convert ID string to integer and store value in IDtemp
StudIDcpy = itoba(IDtemp);//convert integer to binary number as a string
strcpy(StudID, StudIDcpy);
IDtemp = strlen(StudIDcpy);
free(StudIDcpy); // <---- I BELIEVE THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
```

Here is my `itoba()` function:

```
char *itoba(int a){
    int i = 0, j;
    char temp[15];
    while(a){
        if (a % 2)temp[i] = '1';
        else temp[i] = '0';
        i++;
        a = a / 2;
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    for (j = 0; j < i / 2; j++)swapc(&temp[j], &temp[i - j-1]);
    return temp;
}
```

By the way I know I don't have to write `sizeof(char)` because it is equal to 1, but I write it anyways so I remember what value should be put there.

Comment: Be handy to see the code for `itoba`

Comment: I added the code itoba

Comment: `return temp;` returns a pointer to a local variable, which disappears when the function exits.

Comment: Did you compile with warnings enabled?

Comment: You leak the memory allocated on your first 2 lines, you call `free` on local buffer `temp` which doesn't even exist at that point...

Comment: so because temp is not a pointer and StudIDcpy is getting its address so i dont need to allocate memory for it? and also dont need to free it?

Comment: `temp` is on the stack. That disappears at the end of the function. So the pointer is no longer valid

Comment: And FYI, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: See this famous Stackoverflow question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/12711

Comment: @tikanti-man `char temp[15];` allocates memory, and the memory is automatically freed when the function returns. You cannot write `strcpy(StudID, StudIDcpy);` because `StudIDcpy` is pointing to memory that has already been freed.

Comment: COOL!!! i understand... now i need to think of a different way to make my code work... thanks for the help!

Comment: What if i used *temp instead of temp[15]???

Comment: that's ok but the `malloc` should be for the `temp`

Comment: I changed the 'char *itoba(int a)' to 'void itoba(int a,char *temp)' I think this is the best way to go...

Comment: OK but you should also supply length as argument, otherwise the function has no way of avoiding a buffer overflow

Comment: length of what? what would i do with hit? (by the way thank you very much for your help :) )

Comment: I made sure the integer send to the function is not longer then a 4 digit number, so maximum string value could be 14 zeros or ones... so there could not be a buffer overflow. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `itoba()` function, `temp`, a local array, which decays to a pointer to local variables, is returned.

After a function returns, its local variables are "free"ed immediately, allowing these memory space to be reused by someone else. Consequently, values held by them will soon be overridden by other values on the stack.

You can rewrite `itoba()` like this:

```
char *itoba(int a)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    char *temp = malloc(15); // <--- This line is different
    while(a){
        if (a % 2)
            temp[i] = '1';
        else
            temp[i] = '0';
        i++;
        a = a / 2;
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    for (j = 0; j < i / 2; j++)
        swapc(&temp[j], &temp[i - j -1]);
    return temp;
}
```

BTW: You should remove `char *StudIDcpy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);`, because the pointer value returned by `malloc()` is later discarded by `itoba(IDtemp);`. As a result, the memory allocated to `StudIDcpy` by this `malloc()` will never be freed, causing memory leak.